# nested links overlaying

Tags: html, css, wordpress

The inner most nested links are appearing on the second inner most inner nested links. They shouldn't even be displayed until their parent is clicked.

**HTML :**

```
<ul>
    <li class="current-menu-ancestor">
        <a href="#">about us</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="current-menu-ancestor">
                <a href="#">locations</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li class="current-menu-ancestor">
                        <a href="#">georgia</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li class="current-menu-item">
                                <a href="#">atlanta</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

See here: http://guardianwebtest.edulence.com/ashford/locations/main/georgia

3 layers work, but for some reason the fourth gets overlaid. Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: this is probably a browser issue.  I checked and IE9 standards mode fails like you said, but quirks mode displays the list fine (though there are other styling issues).

Comment: yeah, but it doesn't work in any other browser. also, with compatibility on the header nav links get broken.....

Comment: When you first said "nested links" I thought you meant you had nested links. Haha, silly me.

Comment: when I turn off `height: 20px` in `ul.sub-menu li` the problem goes away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by a height being declared in the rule below. If you remove it all the items stop squishing together:

```
#content-wrap #sidebar li ul.sub-menu li ul.sub-menu li,
#content-wrap #sidebar ul.sub-menu li:first-child ul.sub-menu li{
    background: url("images/l-nav-subnav.gif") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    margin-left: 30px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    height: 20px; /* remove this line */
}
```